# How to work on Cast iron and jms adapters?

Tags: jms, ibm-mobilefirst, cast-iron

What is the use of Cast iron and JMS adapters in IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation? How can I execute the Cast iron and JMS adapters?

I have done the SQL and HTTP adapters.
Please give me a solution, how to work with these adapters. Please share sample code or useful links.

Answer (score 1):

You can read more about JMS and Cast Iron adapters, and what they are used for, in the following locations:

- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/js-jms-adapter/
- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/js-cast-iron-adapter/

This is the only available information; consult the IBM RedBooks for more information and possible sample implementation.

Comment: Thanks...... for ur quick reply. I have already referred this links, in JMS adapter what is the JNDI username and password i have to give?

Comment: Of the server you'll use to send the messages from?

Comment: I have gone through the link, but difficult to get the solution..please can you give a detailed ex-plantation.